# How to match and replace over multiple lines in perl

Tags: perl

I am using perl in r but I dont think that makes a difference
I would like to replace a line in a text file (called copy.conf) with another line.

The line is

```
#file1
file = User/me/stuff.txt #This filename can vary
```

I would like to replace this with

```
#file1
file = Another/Path/tostuff.txt
```

In order to do this I need to match #file1 and also the following file = and everything else on that line. So I have tried a multiline match as follows

```
 perl -i -p -e's{#file1\n.*}{#file1\n Another/Path/tostuff.txt}g' /Users/copy.conf
```

Although I don't get an error I also don't get the desired result. On testing it further, the 
    #file1/n

seems to match fine but the 
    .* 
afterwards doesn't.  So I tried using a multiline flag to see if that works as follows:

```
perl -i -p -e's{#file1\n.*/m}{#file1\n Another/Path/tostuff.txt}g' /Users/copy.conf

but I get the same result.
```

Comment: Your problem here appears to be: You need `\n` not `/n`.

Comment: Typo in the question not in real life. I have changed here but the problem still applies

Comment: The second problem is - your `m` pattern modifier - needs to be on the end of the pattern, not embedded. `s{#file1\nfile =.*}{#file1\nfile = Another/Path/tostuff.txt}gm` and `-p` defined an implicit `while` loop.  That's going line by line, so a multi-line match is never going to work.

Comment: This detects  #file1\n but not the .*. The result is that #file1\n gets replaced with Another/Path/tostuff.txt but after that the rest of the line is still there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a fan of one-liners at all, but this will work for you. If the current line begins with `#file1` then it reads the next line, replaces everything after `file =` with the new path, and appends it to `$_`

```
perl -i -pe'$_ .= <> =~ s|file\s*=\s*\K.+|Another/Path/tostuff.txt|r if /^#file1/' copy.conf
```

Answer (score 3):

OK. So problems here are:

- It's `\n` not `/n`.
- your `m` needs to be at the end of the pattern: `s{#file1\nfile =.*}{#file1\nfile = Another/Path/tostuff.txt}gm`
- `-p` defines a while loop around your code that goes line by line. So you need to `local $/;` to slurp the whole lot.

Try instead (doesn't work, bear with me):

```
perl -i.bak -p -0777 -e 's{#file1\n.*}{#file1\nfile = Another/Path/tostuff.txt}mgs;' test.txt
```

Without inlining, this works;

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

local $/;
while ( <DATA> ) {
    s{#file1\nfile =.*}{#file1\nfile = Another/Path/tostuff.txt}gm;
    print;
 }
__DATA__
#file1
file = User/me/stuff.txt #This filename can vary
```

Comment: Tried it but still doesnt eradicate everything after the newline and replace it. Im not quite sure how to make it match stuff on the next line

Comment: Bear with me, having a bit of a fiddle. How much do you want it to be an inline perl command?

Comment: Im trying to run it as one line within r for the sake of simplicity if that's what you mean

Comment: I meant rather - could you call a script, instead of trying to remember a complicated and long perl syntax?

Comment: Guess so. Should be easy to do

Comment: Edited again - I _think_ that should work, but can't see why it doesn't, and am wondering if Windows is making my life miserable.

Comment: OK but it doesnt seem to overwrite the original file

Comment: No. That's because Windows (where I'm testing) won't do an inplace edit. Try removing the `.bak` from `-i.bak`. :)

Comment: Didnt work. I guess an alternative is to do a second search and replace after the first one to replace everything after txtfile  (which is the join between the replaced text and and the new text with txt and everything else on the line removed?

Comment: `BEGIN{local $/}` will have no effect because it is `local` to the `BEGIN` block. use `BEGIN{$/ = undef}` instead. Also, the `-0` command-line option is more concise: use `-0777` for slurp mode

Comment: Doh. Obvious really :/